# Computers does not shows in network place

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, network-share, local-area-network

Computers are not listed in network place, But able access computers using remote desktop or directly typing computer name on address bar (\com_name).

I found FDResPub and SSDPSRV services were disabled on some computers and i started manually,after that  most of the computers are showing.

but some computers are not showing although both services are running

Comment: Their firewall disabled for the test?

Comment: Yes, it is disabled

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Client os are windows 7, domain is windows server 2008 R2

Comment: Why do you need to see them? Have you enabled Network Discovery for the appropriate network profile?

Answer (score 0):

- Just check your windows firewall.. disable it then check that network PC's are showing or not.
- Other solution:- In windows 7 there is option for network to chose that it is "home", "work" or "public" network. Just go network from bottom right corner of your task-bar n/w icon and change the n/w to HOME or WORK n/w.. i think you problem will be solved.
- Turn on the network discovery of your system.

Comment: windows firewall is already disabled, we use only av firewall, i tried with disabling it as well. but no results.